# Which is correct? She said it was more beautiful, didn't she or wasn't it?

Tags: question-tags

1. She said it was more beautiful, didn't she?
2. She said it was more beautiful, wasn't it?

This sentence confused me. Usually we use the tag with the main verb, so "didn't she" is correct, but there are some verbs like *believe, suppose,* and *I don't think* for which we use the tag on the *that* clause. My question is, is the verb *say* in the same group as *suppose* and *believe*?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The *interrogatory tag* has to reflect a **declaration** in reverse polarity. So it's either

> She said, "**It was** more beautiful, *wasn't it*?"

or

> **She said** [that] it was more beautiful, *didn't she*?

Notice that both declarations are positive, so the tag has be negative, i.e., contain a *not*, which in each case is hidden in the contraction *n't*.

Answer (score 0):

She said/thought/believed/supposed it was more beautiful, didn't she?
(didn't for Simple Past)

Answer (score 0):

> She said it was more beautiful, didn't she?

If the question tag wants to stress what she said

> She said it was more beautiful, wasn't it?

If we want to refer to the fact that she was beautiful